# Implementing (+++) to Join JoinList's

Tags: haskell

Related to this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68588/implementing-tag-for-justlist), I wrote the `(+++)` function to join 2 JoinList's:

```
(+++) :: Monoid m => JoinList m a -> JoinList m a -> JoinList m a
(+++) Empty               y                    = y
(+++) x                   Empty                = x
(+++) left@(Single _ _)   right@(Single _ _)   = Append (tag $ Append mempty left right) left right
(+++) left                right                = Append (tag left `mappend` tag right) left right
```

Calling `(+++)` on `jl1` and `jl2` results in:

```
jl1 :: JoinList (Product Integer) String
jl1 = Append (Product 100) (Single (Product 25) "foo") (Single (Product 4) "bar")

jl2 :: JoinList (Product Integer) String
jl2 = Append (Product 50) (Single (Product 25) "bippy") (Single (Product 2) "baz")
```

**Testing**

```
*JoinList> (+++) jl1 jl2
Append (Product {getProduct = 5000}) 
          (Append (Product {getProduct = 100}) 
               (Single (Product {getProduct = 25}) "foo") 
               (Single (Product {getProduct = 4}) "bar")) 
          (Append (Product {getProduct = 50}) 
               (Single (Product {getProduct = 25}) "bippy") 
               (Single (Product {getProduct = 2}) "baz"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I didn't know about the other `JoinList` questions when I was answering the other one one you asked.)

The case

```
(+++) left@(Single _ _)   right@(Single _ _)   =
  Append (tag $ Append mempty left right) left right
```

is redundant. There is no need to distinguish this case, also there is no need to call `tag` on a temporarily created `Append` value. Other than that, it looks good.

Just a remark, using `Product` with `JoinList` probably isn't very meaningful, monoids that provide useful information (depending on the use-case) would be `Sum`, [`Min`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups-0.8/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Min) or `Max`.

For testing, I'd suggest you to study [QuickCheck](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck1). It allows you to define *properties* of your operations and automatically test them for various inputs. It's important to define good properties, in particular they should be distinct from the implementation of your operations. For example, you might want to test: For any `JoinList`s `xs` and `ys`

- if `i < sizeJ xs` then `indexJ i (xs +++ ys) === indexJ i xs`
- if `i >= sizeJ xs` then `indexJ i (xs +++ ys) === indexJ (i - sizeJ xs) ys`

etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Bug

```
(+++) left@(Single _ _)   right@(Single _ _)   = Append (tag $ Append mempty left right) left right
```

case isn't just redundant, it is wrong:

```
>(Single (Product 4) "foo") +++ (Single (Product 5) "bar") 
>Append (Product {getProduct = 1}) (Single (Product {getProduct = 4}) "foo") (Si
gle (Product {getProduct = 5}) "bar")`
```

It should have returned `Append (Product {getProduct = 20}) ....` and not `Append (Product {getProduct = 1}) ....` as `4*5 = 20`.

### Special treatment of `Empty`

Also `Empty` should not be handled specially unless specification **explicitly** asks you to do so, as standard constructors of `JoinList` allows `(Append (Product 1) Empty Empty)`.

### Infix operators

`(+++)` function defines and infix operator. You would generally want to use them in infix form. You can use it in infix form in function definitions also. `(<>)` is an alias for `mappend`, you can use it instead of backquoted `mapped`

Your definition becomes:

```
(+++) :: Monoid m => JoinList m a -> JoinList m a -> JoinList m a
left +++ right = Append (tag left <> tag right) left right
```

You can test it like so:

```
> (Empty +++ Empty)::(JoinList (Product Integer) String)
Append (Product {getProduct = 1}) Empty Empty
> (Single (Product 4) "foo") +++ (Single (Product 5) "bar")
Append (Product {getProduct = 20}) (Single (Product {getProduct = 4}) "foo") (Single (Product {getProduct = 5}) "bar")
> jl1 +++ jl2
...
```