# Implementing `dropJ` to Drop `JoinList` Elements

Tags: haskell

In the same vein as the [(+++) function on JoinList](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68705/implementing-to-join-joinlists) and [indexJ on JoinList](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69347/searching-a-join-list-for-an-index-attempt-2), I implemented `dropJ` to drop elements from a JoinList.

Here's my attempt:

```
dropJ ::(Sized b, Monoid b) => Int -> JoinList b a -> JoinList b a
dropJ _ Empty = Empty
dropJ i jl | i <= 0           = jl
dropJ _ (Single _ _)          = Empty
dropJ i (Append _ left right) 
  | i >= leftHt               = dropJ (i-leftHt) right
  | otherwise                 = dropJ i left
    where leftHt = (getSize. size . tag) left
```

**Testing**

```
*JoinList>jlIndex2
Append (Size 3) 
               (Single (Size 1) "foo") 
               (Append (Size 2) 
                   (Single (Size 1) "bar") 
                   (Single (Size 1) "baz"))

*JoinList> dropJ 1 jlIndex2
Append (Size 2) (Single (Size 1) "bar") (Single (Size 1) "baz")

*JoinList> dropJ 2 jlIndex2
Single (Size 1) "baz"

*JoinList> dropJ 3 jlIndex2
Empty

*JoinList> dropJ 0 jlIndex2
Append (Size 3) 
               (Single (Size 1) "foo") 
               (Append (Size 2) 
                   (Single (Size 1) "bar") 
                   (Single (Size 1) "baz"))
```

Comment: There is a bug. Try `dropJ 1 $ Append (Size 3) (Append (Size 2) (Single (Size 1) "bar") (Single (Size 1) "baz")) (Single (Size 1) "foo")`.

Comment: thank you, [abuzittin](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/20251/abuzittin-gillifirca), for pointing out the bug. I updated `dropJ`'s to `i >= leftHt               = dropJ (i-leftHt) right` Would you expect the `dropJ` result to have the correct **Size**? Perhaps it's implied?

Comment: The bug comes from this case `otherwise = dropJ i left`; and you can fix it like so `otherwise = dropJ i left +++ right`, provided you've already fixed the bug I mentioned in [this answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69363/20251) of mine.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine, but you have a bug in the `Append` case, as you completely disregard the `right` part of the tree:

```
dropJ i (Append _ left right) 
  | i >= leftHt               = dropJ (i-leftHt) right
  | otherwise                 = dropJ i left              -- where is right?
    where leftHt = (getSize. size . tag) left
```

You can fix this if you use `+++` here again:

```
dropJ i (Append _ left right) 
  | i >= leftHt               = dropJ (i-leftHt) right
  | otherwise                 = dropJ i left +++ right
    where leftHt = (getSize. size . tag) left
```

Other than that we could argue about formatting, but your code is fine. It works. Note that you should add more test cases though. A `Arbitrary a => Gen (JoinList m a)` generator might come in handy for QuickCheck, but that's left as an exercise.