# Searching a Join List for an index

Tags: haskell

For the Join List algebraic data type:

```
data JoinList m a = Empty
                  | Single m a
                  | Append m (JoinList m a) (JoinList m a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

This [homework](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/07-folds-monoids.pdf)'s problem states to implement `indexJ`:

> Exercise 2 The first annotation to try out is one for fast indexing
>   into a JoinList . The idea is to cache the size (number of data ele-
>   ments) of each subtree.
>
> This can then be used at each step to deter-
>   mine if the desired index is in the left or the right branch. We have
>   provided the Sized module that defines the Size type, which is simply
>   a newtype wrapper around an Int .
>
> In order to make Size s more
>   accessible, we have also defined the Sized type class which provides a
>   method for obtaining a Size from a value.
>
> indexJ finds the JoinList element at the specified index. If the index
>   is out of bounds, the function returns Nothing. By an index in a
>   JoinList we mean the index in the list that it represents. That is,
>   consider a safe list indexing function

I implemented `indexJ`, which searches for a matching index within a `JList`.

```
indexJ :: (Sized b, Monoid b) => Int -> JoinList b a -> Maybe a
indexJ _ Empty = Nothing
indexJ i (Single s x)
  | (getSize . size) s == i = Just x
  | otherwise               = Nothing
indexJ i (Append _ left right) 
  | (getSize . size . tag) left >= i = indexJ i left
  | otherwise                        = indexJ i right
```

with the following background:

`tag`'s [definition](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68588/implementing-tag-for-justlist)

```
newtype Size = Size Int
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Num)

getSize :: Size -> Int
getSize (Size i) = i

class Sized a where
  size :: a -> Size
```

...

`tag :: Monoid m => JoinList m a -> m`

**Testing**

```
jlIndex1 :: JoinList Size String
jlIndex1 = Append (Size 1) (Single (Size 0) "foo") (Single (Size 1) "bar")

*JoinList> indexJ 1 jlIndex1
Just "bar"
*JoinList> indexJ 33 jlIndex1
Nothing
```

Please critique my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `indexJ` seems to be broken. In particular:

```
indexJ i (Append _ left right) 
  | (getSize . size . tag) left >= i = indexJ i left
  | otherwise                        = indexJ i right
```

indexing with `i` in the right part is wrong. I'd suggest you to create a function that converts a list into a `JoinedList` (ideally a blanced one), and then test if indexing into the list produces the same result as indexing into the `JoinedList`.

Also the implementation of `tag` is missing, but this is a crucial part of the code, without it it can't be really reviewed.

I'd also suggest to implement other operations on `JoinList`s, in particular creating a singleton list and concatenation, perhaps also prepending/appending an element to a list.

Finally, you're using a `Monoid` instance for tagging the tree. This is in general a good idea, but the assignment doesn't say anythong about monoids, sobe sure to understand how the monoid there should be used. You never use the fact that `m` a monoid in your code. If you're unsure, I'd suggest to forget about monoids at this point and use just the provided `Size` data type.

Comment: Could you please look at my second attempt - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69347/searching-a-join-list-for-an-index-attempt-2? Thanks