# Searching a Join List for an index Attempt #2

Tags: haskell, tree

Originally I posted this incorrect attempt - [Searching a Join List for an index](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68706/searching-a-join-list-for-an-index).

Given a `JoinList`:

```
data JoinList m a = Empty
                  | Single m a
                  | Append m (JoinList m a) (JoinList m a)
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

where `m` represents the **size** of the `JoinList`, find the element `(Maybe a)` at the given index in the `JoinList` structure.

```
indexJ :: (Sized b, Monoid b) => Int -> JoinList b a -> Maybe a
indexJ _ Empty             = Nothing
indexJ i (Single _ x) 
  | i == 0                 = Just x
  | otherwise              = Nothing
indexJ i (Append _ left right)
  | leftHt > i             = indexJ i left
  | (rightHt + leftHt) > i = indexJ (i-leftHt) right
  | otherwise              = Nothing
  where leftHt  = (getSize. size . tag) left
        rightHt = (getSize. size . tag) right
```

where `tag` =

```
tag :: Monoid m => JoinList m a -> m
tag Empty          = mempty
tag (Single x _)   = x
tag (Append x _ _) = x
```

**Testing**

**Data**

```
jlIndex2 :: JoinList Size String
jlIndex2 = Append (Size 3) 
                       (Single (Size 1) "foo") 
                       (Append (Size 2) 
                             (Single (Size 1) "bar") 
                             (Single (Size 1) "baz"))

jlIndex3 :: JoinList Size String
jlIndex3 = Append (Size 4) (Single 1 "biz") jlIndex2
```

**Tests**

```
*JoinList> indexJ 3 jlIndex3
Just "baz"
*JoinList> indexJ 0 jlIndex3
Just "biz"
*JoinList> indexJ 100 jlIndex3
Nothing
```

Note - I would've used QuickCheck, but I'm not sure how to use it with algebraic data types.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is completely fine, although the suffix `Ht` for the sublist sizes is a little bit strange.

For the tests you can use

```
genJoinList :: Arbitrary a => Int -> Gen (JoinList Size a)
genJoinList 0 = pure Empty
genJoinList 1 = Single (Size 1) <$> arbitrary
genJoinList n = do
  left <- choose (0, n)
  Append (Size n) <$> (genJoinList left) <*> (genJoinList (n - left))

toList :: JoinList b a -> [a]
toList Empty          = []
toList (Single _ x)   = [x]
toList (Append _ l r) = toList l ++ toList r
```

You can now check whether `indexJ n js` returns the same value as `toList js !! n`:

```
prop_index :: (Eq a, Sized m, Monoid m) => Int -> JoinList m a -> Bool
prop_index n js = indexJ n js == indexI n (toList js)
  where
    indexI n xs = lookup n $ zip [0..] xs

main = quickCheck $ \n -> forAll (sized genJoinList) $ \js -> prop_index n js
```

An `Arbitrary` instance would need `FlexibleInstances` by the way.